# Extjs 5 rowediting only in some conditions

Tags: javascript, extjs, roweditor

Good day all, I have a table in which I use the rowediting feature, and I have this column:

```
{
  text: 'CPL Object',
  dataIndex: 'CPLObj',
  flex: 1,
  editor: {
           allowBlank: false
   }
```

}

now, I'd like to make this column editable, only if another column has a certain value, let's say if the `'model'` column has `'CPU'` as value. Otherwise I'd like to Not have the editor for this value.

Is that possible?

Comment: I?ve solved by adding a listener to the entire table, the 'onbeforeedit' and then adding a function that check if the column has to be edited or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean your using grid? Have you tried adding a formula on your viewModel for checking if the model column you wish to check do have a value? Maybe something like:

```
Viewmodel:
   checkvalue: function(get){
     var x = true;
     if (get('current.model' !== ''){ 
        x = false 
     } 
     return x;
    }


   ViewController: (on your binding)
   column: {
     readonly: '{checkvalue}' 
   }
```